# Help me translate this (particle で, etc.)

Tags: translation, particles, particle-で

Here is the question: how to translate the following sentence to Japanese.

> Inform that the hospital is located between the supermarket and the hotel over there:
>
> **病院にあそこでスーパーとホテルの間があります。**

I want to know if it is right that I use the particle **で** after あそこ and if I committed any other mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

I would say
病院はあのスーパーとホテルの間にあります。 - The hospital is between that supermarket and hotel.

The に particle indicates where something is, so by starting with 病院に, you are saying there is something in the hospital.

You could say something like:
この病院にレストランがあります。- There is a restaurant in this hospital.

The particle で indicates a location where an activity takes place. For instance:
レストランで晩御飯（ばんごはん）を食べました。- I ate dinner at a restaurant.

Also note that the verb ある always takes the に particle, so to say something is somewhere, you would say:
[place]+に+[thing]+がある or
[thing]+は+[place]+に+ある

These really are the very basics though, I would recommend you get some sort of beginner textbook and go through it, I used Genki myself and would recommend it.

Comment: Ok but if i will あそこ wath particle i have to use then? I used the particle で because i thot that " its over there a activity will take place" or something like that..

Comment: @MarcoTulio With あそこ, you would follow the same rules, so you could say 病院はあそこにある。- the hospital is over there. You could also say something like 病院はあそこのホテルとスーパーの間にある。あそこのホテル meaning "the hotel over there".